# Coloring "horizontal line" in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, frontend

Is there anyway to have those lines automatically Black in Mathematica ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default style of those lines is defined in the file `ContextMenus.tr` located in the subdirectory `SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources` of `$InstallationDirectory`. If you search for "CellInsertionPoint" in that file then you should find something like

```
"CellInsertionPoint" -> {
  ....
  Menu["Insert Ho&rizontal Line",
    {
     MenuItem["Thi&n Line", FrontEndExecute[{
       FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], 
        Cell[" ", "Text", 
         ....
         CellFrameColor->RGBColor[0,0,1]], 
       After]
      }]],
     MenuItem["&Medium Line", FrontEndExecute[{
         .....    
         CellFrameColor->RGBColor[0,0,1]], 
       After]
      }]],
     MenuItem["&Thick Line", FrontEndExecute[{   
         .....
         CellFrameColor->RGBColor[0,0,1]], 
       After]
      }]],
  ....
}
```

To permanently change the default colour of the horizontal lines you could set `CellFrameColor` of these three MenuItems to whatever colour you want (or you could create extra MenuItems if you want more choice). Note that you need to restart Mathematica for the changes to take effect.

If you don't want to change the original file you can also save a copy of the file to the appropriate subdirectory in either `$BaseDirectory` or `$UserBaseDirectory` and edit that.

Comment: Thank you Heike, I will use Sjoerd solution for now, when i`ll have time to understand really what is it that we are modifying with you I will implement it !

Answer (score 4):

Heike has the answer, but in the unlikely case you don't want to mess with those .tr files you could also execute

```
NotebookPut[
  NotebookGet[
    SelectedNotebook[]] /. {
      Cell[" ", "Text", x___, CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[___], y___] :> 
      Cell[" ", "Text", x, CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], y]}, 
  SelectedNotebook[]];
```

and turn every cell frame (the lines are just cell frames) black.

Comment: Sjoerd, I will go for that, I don`t want to mess with those file now.

Answer (score 2):

Although it doesn't satisfy the criterion of "automatic", you could just insert the default blue line and then change its color. Since the line is not selectable, you need to click under the line the press shift-up. Then press `Ctrl-Shift-E` (Show Expression) to see (for a thick line)

```
Cell[" ", "Text",
 Editable->False,
 Selectable->False,
 CellFrame->{{0, 0}, {0, 3}},
 ShowCellBracket->False,
 CellMargins->{{0, 0}, {1, 1}},
 CellElementSpacings->{"CellMinHeight"->1},
 CellFrameMargins->0,
 CellFrameColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1],
 CellSize->{Inherited, 5}]
```

Then the RGBColor is easily changed.